# Django Method of Forwarding Non-www to www?

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, url

In django I am wondering if there is a django-designed way to redirect http://www.example.com to http://example.com or the other way around http://example.com > http://www.example.com.

Usually one would use htaccess for this, but it should be a simple issue so I was wondering if there is a design-method to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that, you need to add `PREPEND_WWW` setting to your `settings.py` file.

```
PREPEND_WWW = True  # Default value is False
```

Django will then prepend the `“www.”` subdomain to URLs that don’t have it. So, URLs that lack a leading `“www.”` will be redirected to the same URL with a leading `“www.”`

**Note:** This will work only if `CommonMiddleware` is present in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` settings.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', # must be there in middlewares
   ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only one-way in django, with [`PREPEND_WWW`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#prepend-www):

> Whether to prepend the “www.” subdomain to URLs that don’t have it.
>   This is only used if CommonMiddleware is installed (see Middleware).
>   See also APPEND_SLASH.

However, you server should be configured correctly to recognize the URL and correctly route the request. Otherwise you'll have issues (infinite redirects, for example).